# Не выводится ascii_letters в telebot

Tags: python, строки, telebot, случайные-числа, ascii

Бот должен выдавать рандомное значение из ascii_letters, но почему-то этого не делает. Пытался вывести еще просто в print, но тоже не выходит. Несколько вариантов попробовал, но ничего не получается. Пока что остановился на:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call, payid= (random.choice(ascii_letters))):
        if call.message:
            if call.data == 'yes':
                #payid += random.choice(ascii_letters)
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,'Вот твоя ссылка на оплату: [ссылка позже].\nОбязательно в комментариях к оплате укажи этот код: ', payid)
            elif call.data == 'no':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,'Хорошо, заказ отменен')
```

Если есть ошибка в функции, то прошу прощения, так как больше ничего не смог придумать.

Comment: Что это за функция, что должно происходить? Что находится в ascii_letters? Бот отправляет одно из сообщений?

Comment: ascii_letters импортировал из встроенной библотеки string. Функция отвечает за сообщения, который отправит бот в зависимости от нажатия пользователя на кнопку. Если правильно поняд последний вопрос, то отвечает на одно из сообщений (см. 2 предложение)

Comment: В переменной “payid” бред написал, наверное. Но опыт же таки, я много раз пытался пофиксить баг и остановился на этом бреде в итоге пока что

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Чтобы получить случайную букву с `string` `ascii_letters`:

```
from string import ascii_letters
from random import choice

random_letter = choice(ascii_letters)
print(random_letter) # OUTPUT: P
```

> Вы передаёте `payid= (random.choice(ascii_letters))` в качестве принимающего параметра функции `callback_inline`

> Чтобы получить менее желаемый результат необходимо написать:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
        if call.message:
            if call.data == 'yes':
                payid = choice(ascii_letters)  # Letter in payid
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f'Вот твоя ссылка на оплату: [ссылка позже].\nОбязательно в комментариях к оплате укажи этот код: {payid}')
            elif call.data == 'no':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,'Хорошо, заказ отменен')
```

> К тому же я понял, что вы сами не знаете, что желаете получить, а именно вы хотели бы получить случайное число, не знаю в каком диапазоне, пример оставлю ниже:

```
from random import randint

random_digit = randint(0, 999)
print(random_digit) # OUTPUT: 105
```

Подробнее о string и random читайте в оф. документациях..